# How do I cancel a CV's unsaved draft changes?

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs

I started editing the **Responsibilities** text box of an **Experience** entry.  I decided that I didn't want those changes after all, but I don't know how to cancel them.  I haven't clicked the **Save** button, so it's *not* in my published CV.

I tried reloading the page, but the unwanted changes are still there.  I even tried logging out and logging back in, to no avail.  I do see a "Your CV has unsaved draft changes" in the **status** tab, so clearly this is intentional (and usually desired) behavior.

So how do I cancel/remove the draft?

My expectation was that there'd be a **Cancel** button next to the **Save** button in the **edit cv** tab.  It could be greyed out until a change is made.

Sorry if this is a duplicate.  I tried searching for an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey man, thanks for the report.  Should be fixed now.

You should see a little orange `draft` button next to each field you've changed.  Click the draft button to undo the changes to the associated field.

BTW what do people think of html elements with id's like "float-left"...confusing much?

BONUS: This bug has been around for exactly 4 months today :(